# In bipartite directed graph, how to efficiently find nontrivial edge values such that for each node, sum of edge values is zero?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-mathematics

Suppose I have a set of sources **U** and a set of sinks **V** and a set of directed edges **E** going from elements of **U** to elements of **V**.

I want to find a vector **z** of size **|E|** (each value of **z** is assigned to an edge) such that, for each node in **U** and **V**, the sum of the values assigned to its adjacent edges is zero.

What I have done up to now :

Define **A** of size (|**U**|+|**V**|)x(|**E**|) with **A**(i,j)=1 if edge j is adjacent to node i, 0 otherwise.

All elements of the nullspace of **A** (i.e. **z** s.t. **Az**=0) fit the bill.

But computing the nullspace of a large (even sparse) matrix is expensive. (I have done it through QR factorization using suitesparseQR).

Any suggestion as to a whole different way to do this of a faster way to calculate a random element of the nullspace of a large sparse rectangular matrix is welcome.

Comment: What if there is no non-trivial solution, say $G$ is $1 \to a \gets 2 \to b$?

Comment: Yes, that's a totally valid comment : I suppose that my graph contains at least one cycle, which means that there exists at least one non-trivial solution.

Comment: Then what stops you from finding that cycle and putting $+1, -1$ on it (the graph is bipartite, so the cycle has to be of even length)?

Comment: Well, I was hoping to use that **z** vector to delete cycles, thinking it would be more efficient than looking for cycles in my graph and finding an appropriate way to delete them while maintaining feasibility of my solution.